# Referencing other tables in BigQuery UDF as lookups

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

Is there any way to reference other tables within a Project/Dataset from a BigQuery UDF as lookup tables? I have read the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#limitations) which indicates that it is not possible in Standard SQL; any chance it is available in Legacy?

Also, while I understand that similar behavior can be accomplished with a join, being able to directly reference lookup tables would be infinitely cleaner.

Any other methods of accomplishing similar lookup-type functionality would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible, but you may be interested in the following feature requests:

- [Support for table references inside SQL UDFs](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35906020).
- [Support for parameterized views](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905221).